# All reviews on one page

Tags: review

How can I display all the reviews of the products on a single CMS page? I have found a module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/all-reviews.html, but it is nog compatible with 1.9.

[image]

Comment: what you want?????

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** You can get `review Collection` by below code:

```
$Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setDateOrder();
```

**Step2:** 
Create a Cms page from `admin>Cms>Page>` and at Design tab  and put this code

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="review.form" template="catalog/allreview.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**Step3:** create allreview.phtml on `app/design/frontend/your package/your template/templete/catalog/` and put below  this phtml file 
you can put review details by below code:

```
<?php
    $_items = array_reverse( $Collection->getItems());

    foreach ($_items as $_review):
        $productId =  $_review->getentity_pk_value();
         $_review->getTitle();
         $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
         $_review->getDetail()
          $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()) ?>
              $this->__('[Posted %s]', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long');

    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: But what I have to do at step 1? Step 2 and 3 are done, but the page on the frontend is showing the code from step 3.

Comment: please ckd... i have update

Comment: I still get a screen with the code of step 3..

Comment: can you post the screen shot...

Comment: You can see it in my question

Comment: Do you know a solution?

Comment: why you did not put code under page code.It is soo sample

Comment: I don't know what you exactly mean

Comment: on phtml file you need to put step3 code  under php tag <?php ?>

Comment: Now my CMS page on frontend is blank.

Comment: i have check my system .it was working.

Comment: Is there something I have to do with the code of step 1? I have done step 2 and 3 as you described.

Comment: Do I have someting to do with this code: $Collection=Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setDateOrder();

Answer (score 0):

in your magento backend
 system-perssions-blocks 
click  "add new block"
create a new  block name "allreviews/allreviews"
set  allowed 
that will slove this problem

Comment: perssions.....?

Answer (score 0):

Call a phtml file in cms page and call below code in the phtml file:

```
$_reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();
foreach($_reviews as $review){
// load the product for the corresponding review if You need to display product information
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getData('entity_pk_value'));
$j=0;
$cumulative = 0;
foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
$cumulative +=$vote->getPercent();
$j++;
}
$finalPercentage = 0;
if ($cumulative != 0){
$finalPercentage = ($cumulative/$j);
}
}//close the foreach
?>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.